# Mix text resources

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I have two string resources into `Errors.resx` file something like this:

```
Name                    Description

SUPPORT_CallTo          Call to XXXXXXXX   
DOCUMENT_CantDoIt       Can't proccess doc {0}, please {1}
```

I want to use `SUPPORT_CallTo` as parameter `{1}` for `DOCUMENT_CantDoIt`, but directly in the designer.

I don't want to write something like this:

```
String.format(Errors.DOCUMENT_CantDoIt,"something here",Errors.SUPPORT_CallTo)
```

each time I use `DOCUMENT_CantDoIt`.

Can I mix these two resources directly from the designer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't unless you write your own processor that reads the string and replaces instances of embedded resources.

You could opt for a format that you can replace with regex, like;

> Can't proccess doc {0}, please #SUPPORT_CallTo#.

Then you can use a regular expression like:

```
#(.*?)#
```

Then use the `ResourceManager` to get the resource manually and replace it in the text.